# React set text content but not html

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm wondering if there is a React equivalent of setting node.textContent to defend against scripting attacks. Currently I am just doing

```
<p>{name}</p>
```

But of course this isn't text content and could be prone to attacks. I want to avoid having to do sanitization if a direct textcontent is possible.

Comment: https://www.stackhawk.com/blog/react-xss-guide-examples-and-prevention/ Here's a great write-up on the problem. For your particular use case, no issue, but there are ways that injecting markup can end up causing problems, in which case this article suggests several solutions.

Answer (score 0):

By default, React sanitizes text content. To directly set html you need to use the [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) attribute.